# Why does console say my function/variable is undefined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, load, jquery-animate, document-ready

I have a sidebar script that I am creating a separate js file for since it is used in 3 areas of a website. When I check the console, it says its undefined.

Here is my script, what am I missing?

```
var SideBarMenu = (function() {
var init = function() {
    debug('sideBarMenu.init');
    $('.sidebar_menu').show();
    setTimeout("SideBarMenu.hideSideBar()",3000);
};

var hideSideBar = function () {
    $('.sidebar_menu').slideUp('300');
    $('.sidebar').mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
};

var handlerIn = function () {
    //debug('sideBarMenu enter');
    $('.sidebar_menu').slideDown('300');
}
var handlerOut = function () {
    //debug('sideBarMenu leave');
    $('.sidebar_menu').slideUp('300');
}

return {
    init:init,
    hideSideBar:hideSideBar
};
})();
});
```

Comment: You probably close your `$().ready(function() { ... });` too early. Please indent your code correctly and you will see such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many `.ready()` handlers as you want. Simply wrap your logic in another.

See: [http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMultiple_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Comment: Ok, so I added it to the individual pages in this fashion:

$(document).ready(function () {
   sideBarMenu.init();
    });

That now shows it loading but says the function is not defined. What am I missing in my original script?

Comment: Is the .js file that contains your code included before or after the file that contains the code in your comment?